# raspberry pi lightning dma pwm flickery

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I'm using the lightning drivers with windows IoT core to drive a PWM output. I've attached a scope to the GPIO pin and I set the PWM duty cycle. I do this in an infinite loop. If I put a delay in the loop then the output signal looks fine. If I drop the delay however, the duty cycle (as seen on the scope) starts to flicker between 5 and 10%. Code below, can anyone explain this?

```
        var controllers = await PwmController.GetControllersAsync(LightningPwmProvider.GetPwmProvider());
        var pwmController = controllers[1];
        pwmController.SetDesiredFrequency(50);

        var motor1 = pwmController.OpenPin(5);
        motor1.Start();

        do
        {
            motor1.SetActiveDutyCyclePercentage(0.05);
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        } while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but could it be that SetActiveDutyCyclePercentage will actually reset the PWM counter, so it'll mess up the current cycle in the PWM. If you do it repeatedly then it'll mess up a lot of the cycles, vs. putting in a delay. Think about PWM as a counter that flips the output when it hits 0. If you reset the counter (with the SetActiveDutyCyclePercentage call) then the current cycle's total number of counts = length (before it flips the output) will be skewed.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable suggestion to. Unfortunately if that is true it renders the DMA pwm pretty much useless to me. Hopefully this is just an iot bug and will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Might it help if we check on the RP2 pwm driver code? https://github.com/ms-iot/bsp/tree/master/drivers/pwm/bcm2836

Comment: Why do you have to change the PWM duty cycle so rapidly (not suggestion that's wrong, I'm just curious)?

Comment: I was trying to use the lightning DMA PWM output to provide the signal input to an ESC to control brushless DC motors for a basic quadcopter experiment. I had the PWM all working and even added voltage level shifters to take the 3V RP3 PWM outputs to 5V as required by the ESC, then I noticed this erratic PWM output.